# When Calling a api for the Nth time, I get a JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, get, python-requests

I am trying to get statistics for NFL teams from the SportsRadar api. You are required to call each team individually, using a given ID. So instead of manualy calling a api 32 times. I am using a for statment to call only the teams playing in a given week. Unfortunately, this is causing the error `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`.

```
    HomeCall = requests.get("http://api.sportradar.us/nfl-ot2/seasontd/2016/REG/teams/"+teams[homeidkey]+"/statistics.json?api_key=z45b8e45rg282tyqq686g5n5").json()

    AwayCall = requests.get("http://api.sportradar.us/nfl-ot2/seasontd/2016/REG/teams/"+teams[awayidkey]+"/statistics.json?api_key=z45b8e45rg282tyqq686g5n5").json()

    hometouchdowns = HomeCall["record"]["touchdowns"]["total"]
    homepasstouchdowns = HomeCall["record"]["touchdowns"]["pass"]
    homerushtouchdowns = HomeCall["record"]["touchdowns"]["rush"]
    homerushyards = HomeCall["record"]["rushing"]["yards"]
    homepassyards = HomeCall["record"]["passing"]["yards"]

    awaytouchdowns = AwayCall["record"]["touchdowns"]["total"]
    awaypasstouchdowns = AwayCall["record"]["touchdowns"]["pass"]
    awayrushtouchdowns = AwayCall["record"]["touchdowns"]["rush"]
    awayrushyards = AwayCall["record"]["rushing"]["yards"]
    awaypassyards = AwayCall["record"]["passing"]["yards"]
```

It Errors out after the second team is called. Any Help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Make the request manually through your browser? See if you've hit any API limits.

Comment: Check the Response Status before calling `.json`.

Comment: Im getting a 403 Error